# Excel IF Formula to handle more than one possible value in cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

The following is able to handle only "No Access" text in the specified cells.
How can I alter them to handle "Covered" & "Damaged" to display "" (null string) if true, else carry on with formulating.

**Column G formula**

```
=IF(OR(L18="No Access",$J18="No Access")," ",(L18-$J18)*1000)
```

**Column I, K & M Formula**

```
=IF(H18 = "No Access","No Access",(H18-$C18)*1000)
```

**Column N formula**

```
=IF(M18="No Access", " ",
IF(ABS(M18)>ABS(F18),"Exceeded PD Level",
IF(AND(ABS(M18)>ABS(E18), ABS(M18)<ABS(F18)),"Exceeded Alert Level",
" ")))
```

**As requested, here's the values I need to handle**
[image]

- Column `I`,`K` & `M` are calculated base on the values in the column before them
- Column `N` refer to value in Column `M` & compares it with value in Column `E` & `F`, displaying various messages to if column M hit the range specified.

Comment: It isn't clear what your actual question is.  Can you show us _one_ formula and how you want it to behave?

Comment: A screenshot is worth a thousand words, too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen uploaded a screenshot on the values I wish to handle

Comment: @jeffreyweir there's the screenshot

Comment: Not much clearer, I'm afraid. Column headers would have helped. You need to edit your question so that it explains to say a work colleague in plain English what it is you are doing, what all those columns are, and what result you want. Otherwise you're on your own.

Comment: @jeffreyweir i just updated the screenshot, feel free to ask any further questions. I have also put in some pointers explaining the function of some columns

Comment: Maybe you should try the nested if.  And maybe you should provide some [mcve], the new edit for `column I, K, M, N` is related to your question?

Comment: @Prisoner yup, i have actually followed it, I'll organize my codes to explain where each of it goes

Comment: @Prisoner Okay, i'll go research on nested if. Not really confident on solving but no harm trying right. Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming your alter words are these (Please extend below for any more)):

- No Access
- Covered
- Damaged

---

*There where two approaches I have introduced*

### 1. Please correct your formulas in this form:

**Column G formula**

```
=IF(OR(L18="No Access",L18="Covered",L18="Damaged",$J18="No Access",$J18="Covered",$J18="Damaged")," ",(L18-$J18)*1000)
```

**Column I, K & M Formula**

```
=IF(OR(H18 = "No Access",H18 = "Covered",H18="Damaged"),"No Access",(H18-$C18)*1000)
```

**Column N formula**

```
=IF(OR(M18="No Access",M18="Covered",M18="Damaged"), " ",
IF(ABS(M18)>ABS(F18),"Exceeded PD Level",
IF(AND(ABS(M18)>ABS(E18), ABS(M18)<ABS(F18)),"Exceeded Alert Level",
" ")))
```

---

### 2. Use this array form formula to handle any more/ other alters easier:

Follow these *3* steps

1. Use a helper column, for example column `X` (It can be hided), and
   enter all of your alter words in this column.
2. Create a `Name` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + F3), for example
   `Alters` and set `Refers to` field to your helper column range. (for example `$X$1:$X$10`)
3. Write this formula in appropriated cells and then press
   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to running formula against pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Column G formula**

```
=IF(OR(L18=Alters,$J18=Alters)," ",(L18-$J18)*1000)
```

**Column I, K & M Formula**

=IF(H18 = Alters,"No Access",(H18-$C18)*1000)

**Column N formula**

```
=IF(M18=Alters, " ",
IF(ABS(M18)>ABS(F18),"Exceeded PD Level",
IF(AND(ABS(M18)>ABS(E18), ABS(M18)<ABS(F18)),"Exceeded Alert Level",
" ")))
```

*In this brief form you can Edit, Add or Remove any Alter words as you want in your helper column.*

Comment: Thanks, I managed to use nested if to come up with a solution. Appreciate the help though

Comment: I'll give you a tick for the effort though